# Descriptive word to describe nonprofit organization

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Looking for a descriptive word or phrase to describe a nonprofit organization that includes the essence, values, mission and promotion of social reform. Not a place, or agency, business, but a word that describes more of the efforts, people, community, etc. Could be a word that suggests growing, building, promoting change, movement.

An all encompassing word describing the entity.

The sentence is in a letter to volunteers and supporters that starts with "without each and every one of you, we would not be able to create this amazing (need word).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

synergy - The interaction or cooperation of two or more organizations, substances, or other agents to produce a combined effect greater than the sum of their separate effects.

Comment: Like a Sharknado.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider:

> **environment**: (noun) the conditions that surround someone or
>   something : the conditions and influences that affect the growth,
>   health, progress, etc., of someone or something

*from m-w.com*

Comment: That is a great one that I hadn't thought of. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: To spice it up, you can use [metabiotic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/metabiosis): A mode of life in which one organism so depends on another that it cannot flourish unless the latter precedes and influences the environment favorably. A *metabiotic environment*.